# PyQt4 Application Launch

Tags: python, pyqt4

Alright, so I have two applications that won't launch now, a important one and a test one, the test one used to run, but now it is saying: `AttributeError: 'StartQt4' object has no attribute 'filename'`

So, I have no idea why that is happening, and that only happens when I try to use either the save feature or open feature.

Here is the launch code for that app:

[Link to the code](http://tinypaste.com/fe6ba)

Now, the important app is for a project at school, I have made it in PyQt, and just tried launching it using this code:
[Code](http://tinypaste.com/e5609)

If you need the ui file to the second code, just ask and I'll post a DL Link.

I would love to get both of those working, soon! And any tips on some good PyQt tutorials? They also have to be compatible with Python 3...

Answer (score 0):

What did you change between it working and not working?

For the test code without knowing what the `Ui_LQNotepad` class does it's hard to say, but `QMainWindow` objects don't have a `filename` attribute so your code as given will never have worked. I suspect you may mean `self.ui.filename` but I can't say for certain that the `Ui_LQNotepad` class has a `filename` attribute. Search your code for `filename` and you'll see that you only ever read that attribute, you never set it. Where should this filename come from?

I'm not clear on the difference your your test app and the main code, they seem to be pretty much the same so I think the same applies to that.

Please not that in future it is helpful if you post the full traceback as well as the exception message.

Answer (score 0):

Answer are in exception : 'StartQt4' object has no attribute 'filename'.

Just add `filename` attribute in your `__init__`.

```
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
    self.ui = Ui_LQNotepad()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.button_open,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.file_dialog)
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.button_save,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.file_save)
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.charInput,QtCore.SIGNAL("textChanged()"), self.enable_save) 
    self.filename = ""
    self.ui.button_save.setEnabled(False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, one problem was that in the test code, the website with the tutorial actually had a error, so I found it myself, and my project code had a problem with importing a module that was useless and just causing errors.